# How to convert a csv file to a Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, yaml

I have a csv file which has the configuration information to create the yaml file (final desired result). Firstly, I am trying to convert each row of the csv file to a Dictionary and then I can easily convert Dictionary to yaml file using yaml.dump(Created_Dictionary)

Sample Input file (test.csv):

```
fieldname|type|allowed|coerce
field_A|String|10,20,30|to_str
field_B|Integer||to_int
```

My source code using pandas library:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", "|")
df_to_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print(df_to_dict) # print the dictionary

test_yaml = yaml.dump(df_to_dict)
print(test_yaml) # print the yaml file
```

Output I am getting for dictionary(df_to_dict):

```
[{'fieldname': 'field_A', 'type': 'String', 'allowed': '10,20,30'}, {'fieldname': 'field_B', 'type': 'Integer', 'allowed': nan}]
```

Output I am getting for yaml (test_yaml):

```
- allowed: 10,20,30
  fieldname: field_A
  type: String
- allowed: .nan
  fieldname: field_B
  type: Integer
```

Desired dictionary output (df_to_dict) is:

```
[
  {'field_A':
          {'type': 'String', 'allowed': '10,20,30', 'coerce': to_str}
       },
  {'field_B':
          {'type': 'String',  'allowed': '', 'coerce': to_int}
       } 
]
```

Desired yaml output (test_yaml) is:

```
field_A:
  type: String
  allowed: 
  - '10'
  - '20'
  - '30'
  coerce: to_str
field_B:
  type: Integer
  allowed:
  coerce: to_int
```

I see that the variable, df_to_dict, is a list of dictionaries. Do I have to loop through  each list item and then build the dictionary for each row ?  I am not understanding the correct approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your desired dictionary output contains information not available in your CSV. Where do you get all the extra fields/data from?

Comment: If you don't need or want Pandas, Python's standard csv library and DictReader class can handle this; solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need Pandas, and I don't see any need for it in your description or your example, use Python's built-in **csv** library, and its **DictReader** class.

```py
import csv
import pprint

yaml_d = {}
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        fname = row['fieldname']
        allowed = row['allowed'].split(',')

        yaml_d[fname] = row             # "index" row by fieldname
        yaml_d[fname]['allowed'] = allowed

        del yaml_d[fname]['fieldname']  # remove now-extraneous fieldname from row


pprint.pprint(yaml_d)
```

gets me:

```py
{'field_A': {'allowed': ['10', '20', '30'],
             'coerce': 'to_str',
             'type': 'String'},
 'field_B': {'allowed': [''], 'coerce': 'to_int', 'type': 'Integer'}}
```

Comment: I like this idea too because it gives me more control while iterating.

Do you know how I can get the allowed as a yaml list ? screenshot above.

Comment: @Aady, I'm not sure how `yaml.dump()` works, but I think my edit above will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", "|")
my_dict = df.set_index("fieldname").to_dict("index")

#convert allowed items to list
df["allowed"] = df["allowed"].str.split(",")
test_yaml = yaml.dump(df.set_index("fieldname").to_dict("index"), sort_keys=False)
```

###### Output:

```
>>> my_dict
{'field_A': {'type': 'String', 'allowed': '10,20,30', 'coerce': 'to_str'},
 'field_B': {'type': 'Integer', 'allowed': nan, 'coerce': 'to_int'}}

>>> print(test_yaml)
field_A:
  type: String
  allowed:
  - '10'
  - '20'
  - '30'
  coerce: to_str
field_B:
  type: Integer
  allowed: .nan
  coerce: to_int
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution; it seems to work but if the field names are like below, dictionary output seems to be good but the yaml output is reordered in an ascending order based on field name. Try the following input file

```
fieldname|type|allowed
field_A|String|10,20,30
Z_field|Integer|
field_B|String|111
A_filed|Date|11042021
```

Comment: @Aady - I edited my answer. Include the `sort_keys=False` to retain original order.

Comment: Thanks again. But how can I get the allowed values as a yaml list. You can see the desired output above. 
Also, can I use if statement here to invoke a function for coerce ? ie. if string, coerce = to_str; if integer, coerce = to_int

Comment: @Aady - I edited it again. Please stop asking follow-up questions in the comments and/or changing your original question. Post a new question if needed and link this one if it's related.

Answer (score 1):

You want to play around with the index of your pandas DataFrame.

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="|", index_col=0)
>>> df
              type   allowed
fieldname                   
field_A     String  10,20,30
field_B    Integer       NaN
>>> df.to_dict(‘index’) # returns dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
{'field_A': {'type': 'String', 'allowed': '10,20,30'}, 'field_B': {'type': 'Integer', 'allowed': nan}}
>>> print(yaml.dump(df.to_dict(‘index’)))
field_A:
  allowed: 10,20,30
  type: String
field_B:
  allowed: .nan
  type: Integer
```

The `.nan` you have to deal with a custom dump or filter.

See

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html